# Displaying Hebrew text in ASP

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, character-encoding

I am working on ASP application that reads data from sql server and displays it in a table. All my Hebrew text is replaced with "?????".

I installed and Configured Hebrew Font in Regional options. I have set the appropriate Charset in Head,Meta tag
I am able to see proper Hebrew text in sqlServer2005ManagementSudioExpress.
I have proper collation set for my Column (SQL_Latin1_General_CP1255_CI_AS) which is Hebrew. 
I still see "?????" isntead of Hebrew text.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: I am testing in IE, but, it doesnt work in any of the browsers though.

Comment: Try view - > encoding in IE and see if the option selected. Change it and try.

Comment: Appropriate charset? If your table is Unicode, the appropriate charset appears to be Unicode (UTF-8 or UCS-2, not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the column is set to store Unicode. For example, `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`, or `ntext` instead of `text`.